# Blob Tracking With B&W Image

Tags: c#, image, video, tracking

I would like to implement a multiple blob tracking algorithm,
I have a feed of bitmaps (30 bitmaps per second).

The first bitmap for example looks like this:
[image]

And the second image looks like that:
[image]

I want to be able to know that object #1 in the first image is object #1 in the second image, and so with object #2. In addition I want to want to be able the get the blob surrounding the object in the image.

The second step is very easy to implement with somthing like openCV, but to know that 2 blob are the same object is someting i couldn't succeed to implement.

My goal is to archive something like [this](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~flw/tracker/ant.html):

Please advice,
Noam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you identified the blobs you can calculate each blob's [moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) - [here is a link that shows you how using OpenCv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html). Then the vector of moments can be used as a descriptor for this blob. Different descriptors can then be  compared (for instance by calculating the distance between them) to determine if they are similar enough to be the same object.

Comment: I hope it will work for you. Something similar worked really well for me once. It is all about finding some distinctive descriptor that is also fast to calculate.

Comment: Do you know if this example is exist in the C# opevCV port? I am not really strong at C :(

Comment: What if the object changes its shape a little bit during the movement? Thanks for all the help

Comment: No idea. But it makes sense to create a Visual C++ wrapper for OpenCV yourself. This way your only dependency is OpenCV itself which is a plus.

Comment: Pattern matching is never an exact science. You have to make sure (while evaluating techniques) that multiple images of the same object and their descriptors still form clusters in your descriptor space that are far apart from each other.